# I'm getting ERROR [hybrisHTTP13] [DBPersistenceManager] typePK or Code was NULL in getPersistenceInfoInternal()

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

Attributes added in items.xml

[image]

```
ERROR [solrclient-cleanup-master] [DBPersistenceManager] typePK or Code was NULL in getPersistenceInfoInternal()
ERROR [solrclient-cleanup-master] [DBPersistenceManager] typePK or Code was NULL in getPersistenceInfoInternal()
ERROR [solrclient-cleanup-master] [FlexibleSearch] Flexible search error occured...
ERROR [solrclient-cleanup-master] [FlexibleSearch] Query translation was not successful.  
WARN  [solrclient-cleanup-master] [DefaultSolrClientPool] cannot search unknown field 'TableField(name='uid',langPK='null',type=Customer)' within type Customer unless you disable checking, infoMap=TypeInfoMap for type = null
  code = null
  superType = null
  itemTable = null
  UPTable = null
  LTableName = null
  PropsTable = null
  core fields =  []
  unlocalized fields =  []
  localized fields =  []
)
de.hybris.platform.jalo.flexiblesearch.FlexibleSearchException: cannot search unknown field 'TableField(name='uid',langPK='null',type=Customer)' within type Customer unless you disable checking, infoMap=TypeInfoMap for type = null
  code = null
  superType = null
  itemTable = null
  UPTable = null
  LTableName = null
  PropsTable = null
  core fields =  []
  unlocalized fields =  []
  localized fields =  []
```

I am encountering an error in my Java application that uses the Hybris ecommerce platform. When attempting to perform a flexible search query, I am seeing the following error message in the logs:

```
ERROR [solrclient-cleanup-master] [FlexibleSearch] Query translation was not successful.
WARN  [solrclient-cleanup-master] [DefaultSolrClientPool] cannot search unknown field 'TableField(name='uid',langPK='null',type=Customer)' within type Customer unless you disable checking, infoMap=TypeInfoMap for type = null
de.hybris.platform.jalo.flexiblesearch.FlexibleSearchException: cannot search unknown field 'TableField(name='uid',langPK='null',type=Customer)' within type Customer unless you disable checking, infoMap=TypeInfoMap for type = null
```

This error seems to suggest that the flexible search query is attempting to search for an unknown field within the "Customer" type, but the field is not defined. Can anyone provide insight into what might be causing this error, and how I can resolve it?

Comment: please share code snippet, where you are preparing the flexible search query.

Answer (score 0):

After adding the properties, you need to compile your code, execute a hac update and sometimes restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error persistently and was not able to find a proper solution on any forum.

On debugging, I found that the property value for '**db.type.system.name**' was the culprit.

I had an entry for this property in my local.properties file.

I simply removed the property and Voila! It resolved the issue for me.